# AWS Cognito user pool group precedence - working as expected and useless or broken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

**tl;dr**:

What is the purpose of being able to add users to multiple groups in a user pool if the group with higher precedence overrides the role of the group with lower precedence? (Instead of stacking the roles)

**Situation:**

Cognito user pool with 2 groups.
Group 'A' has a role with full access to Dynamo with a precedence of 10
Group 'B' has a role with full access to Elastic Search with a precedence of 9

If I add a user to either group alone it works as expected.

**However**

- if I add a user to group 'A' and 'B', I'd expect them to have permissions from both groups.
- it seems the documented functionality states that the user will just have the permissions from group 'B'. If this is the case, what is the purpose of adding users to multiple groups?

I assumed the purpose of being able to add users to multiple groups would be to have the roles stack instead of overwrite. This way...:

- group A could have perms 1,2,3 with precedence 10
- group B could have perms 4,5,6 with precedence 9
- group C could have perms with DENY on 1 with precedence 8

Could result like so:

- Users in A and B would have perms 1,2,3,4,5,6
- User in A, B, and C would have perms 2,3,4,5,6

But in reality:
- Someone in A and B has perms 4,5,6
- Someone in A, B, and C has no permissions

Comment: For those stumbling across this from a search engine, here is [the section of the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html#assigning-precedence-values-to-groups) which covers Cognito group precedence.

Answer (score 4):

It is expected behavior. If you want permissions from both of the groups you'll just have to create another group/role with combined permissions. Groups are for separating users. At any time a user can assume only one role. You can either let cognito decide which role it will assume based on precedence or you can specify it in GetCredentialsForIdentity custom role ARN. Also you can switch between roles behind the scenes whenever you want by calling GetCredentialsForIdentity and switching the role ARN and Make calls using the credentials for specific role.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the use case is: `If (user has group) { get role Arn for group, get credentials for user with role Arn }` I suppose that makes sense as stacking roles doesn't really exist anywhere on AWS. Though it seems like there would be a lot of calls to getCredentials if you have a user that needs perms from group A, B, and C to do a task. Unless one needs to mix and match groups with a large number of groups, it seems like it would be more efficient to just create a group with combined permissions.

Comment: You can make 3 get credentials calls and save the credentials till they expire. But yes, creating a group/role with combined privileges makes more sense.

Answer (score -3):

The permission from better precedence group will be taken when a user is in multiple groups. If you want to give a user the permissions of multiple groups, you can define multiple groups with the same precedence.

Comment: NOT TRUE, this will result in:

com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: The ambiguous role mapping rules for: cognito-idp.REGION.amazonaws.com/POOL_ID denied this request. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException;

Comment: see https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-service-with-cognito/issues/6